# response.sendRedirect lanza error

Tags: java, jsp, excepciones

Tengo una página web sencilla con jsp, cuando cierro sesión uso:

```
request.getSession().invalidate();
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
```

Para eliminar la sesión y redirigir a la página principal.

Pero si el usuario pulsa atrás al navegador puedes ver la página de nuevo (entiendo que la página cacheada) ya que si refrescamos la página en lugar de aparecer el nombre de usuario aparece "null".

Para evitar esto, pongo un if en las páginas para comprobar que tenga sesion y redirija a la página de error:

```
if(session.getAttribute("nombre_usuario") == null) {
    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp?txtErr=Debe registrarse en la aplicación.&urlErr=index.jsp");
}
```

Pero me genera una excepción la linea de `response.sendRedirect`:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:518)
>       at org.apache.jsp.usuarios_jsp._jspService(usuarios_jsp.java:96)

¿Sabéis que puede ser?

Comment: Como ya invalidadeste la sesión, en tu if está ya es nula session = null, intenta con if(session!=null) {...} , para manejar cuando el usuario regrese apoyate de Js

Comment: @Voiser esa linea no falla, la que lanza la excepcion es la linea ´response.sendRedirect´

Comment: If the response has already been committed, this method throws 
an IllegalStateException. 
After using this method, the response should be considered 
to be committed and should not be written to.

Tu request ya envió un response  y tu deseas volver a enviar otro, esto no es posible ya que para volver a enviar el response debe antes existir  otro request

Comment: @Voiser más que "enviar un response", yo diría "escribió algo en el outputStream" (posiblemente la cabecera del HTML). Dicho esto, este tipo de tareas son ideales para un **Filtro HTTP**, no para copiar-pegar el mismo código en los 200 JSPs. Y dicho esto, me duele en el alma ver que la URL a la que se redirige no está codificada con URLEncoder. Y dicho esto...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una solución pon el siguiente Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         {
            if(history.forward(1))
            location.replace(history.forward(1));
         }
</script>
```

Esto evita que puedas navegar hacia atrás en el navegador en los templeate que tu requieras que no tenga caso o no debería regresar hacia atrás.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta compañero, pero busco una solución en Java / JSP